# How to convert List View items to Json Format

Tags: android, json

I am developing a food booking app.The app has a cart which lists carted items in a list view. How to get all values from cart list view to 
JSON format.Below is a sample format,my data should be like this.

```
{
    "customer_id":"12",
    "product_details": [
                       {"proid":"1", "proname":"abc"},
                       {"proid":"1", "proname":"abc"},
                       {"proid":"3", "proname":"hh"},
                       {"proid":"4", "proname":"gg"}
                   ]
}
```

Comment: see `JSONObject` (or `JsonWriter` for streaming purposes) class documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// try this code

```
    JSONObject input      = new JSONObject();
                JSONArray array       = new JSONArray();

                for (int i = 0; i < alSets.size(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject obj_set1 = new JSONObject();                    
                    String setNo= "Set " + String.valueOf(i+1);
                    obj_set1.put("SetId", i + 1);
                    array.put(obj_set1);
                }
                input("Key", input);

JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(requestURL,input, stringListener, errorListener);

        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                30000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        addToRequestQueue(request);
```

Comment: how to send it to server

Comment: @niyasnazar have edited my answer please check now

Comment: Note : I have used the volley library to send request to server.

Comment: what is "alSets"?

Comment: Thanks for your update

Comment: @niyasnazar Please accept the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163298/discussion-between-mohit-kalia-and-niyas-nazar).

Answer (score 1):

Add following dependency

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
```

And then use

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
gson.toJson(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

A JSON serializing library like Gson is good for this. Simply annotate your model class:

```
@SerializedName("customer_id") private int customerId;
@SerializedName("product_details") private List<ProductDetails> productDetails;

// etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Used [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) read the documentation.